# iOS - Animations inside Navigation Bar doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uinavigationbar, quartz-core

I have a scenario where I needed to add an animation inside the Navigation Bar, but the simulator doesn't animate. I add a UIView, add a label/text field and create outlets for the constraints and update them with "UIView animateWithDuration:" Instead, the simulator just updates the constraints and displays the view accordingly, but without any animation. I have tried it by modifying both constraints as well as frames (separately).

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
[UIView animateWithDuration: 3
                      delay: 0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations: ^{
                     self.constraint.constant += 60;
                     NSLog(@"inside animation");
                     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

This is shown when I increment the width constraint by "60" in viewDidLoad: . And it comes out non-animated.

[image: viewDidLoad, update - yes, but no animation]

When I configure the constraints (increment width by "60") through a button click, even a static updation doesn't happen.

[image: button click, no update, no animation]

The same code works perfectly outside the navigation bar inside the UIView, though.

Appreciate any help...

Comment: Why don't you try out a custom navigation bar?

Comment: did you try by adding a uiview to navigation bar and do the animation in that view?

Comment: @T_77 Yes, I did exactly that. Sorry I forgot to mention that. I added a UIView in the navigation bar and added the label on top of it.
Plus its not because of my messy code. I tried it with a fresh project, and the result is the same :(

Comment: @manish_kumar hmm.. I'll try that. But, why do you think that a custom navigation would solve the problem?

Comment: By custom navigation bar I mean a `UIView` that will work as navigation bar. By this you can easily work and add whatever feature you want.

Comment: I had a same requirement where I had to animate search field and icon. I tried by default navigation bar, but couldn't work out. Then i tried using UIView and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Are you, for any reason, **not** using `theViewYouAdded.masksToBounds = YES;`? Maybe the view is changing its constraint but it doesn't affect the search field.

Comment: @AlejandroIván Wait, maybe I'm wrong, but does layer.masksToBounds do anything other than clipping subviews to a UIView's boundaries?

Comment: @manish_kumar : Does work :). Maybe you'd want to post an answer with some code?

Answer (score 0):

If your navigation bar contains some animation, then you could try out drawing custom navigation bar. Here's what you've to do :

1. In your view controller in `viewDidLoad()` method add the following code

   `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;`
2. After that using a `UIView` create a custom navigation bar with frame adjusted to be visible and top.

After that add components on the view and start working with animations.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've solved this at last. Phew...

What I did was...

1. Added a view in place of barButtonItem (let's call this "superView") and over it another view (and let's call  this "subView") so that I get the following configuration.

[image]

2. Constraints were set between subView and objects on top of it. Now, I created outlets (superView and subView) for superView and subView, made them transparent (optional, of course).

   Useful note: Set the superView's width to the default bar button item's width and the subView's to the screen width. Disable "Clip Subviews" on superView but enable on the subView.
3. Added animations as needed where I had wanted, but layoutIfNeeded on the "superView", not the parent view.

   ```
   [self.superView layoutIfNeeded];
   ```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by taking custom UIView and create width NSLayoutConstraint outlet to it and in code you can handle the constant property of this variable by calling UpdateConstraintsIfNeeded or UpdateViewConstraints method before calling animation code